# how to fetch a rows based on single value

Tags: perl, csv

Suppose i have csv file

```
sno name amnt
1  Larry  8500
2  wall   2500
3  Perl   8500
4  admin  2500
5  sytem  1200
...............
...............
...............
like so on
```

if i have amnt value 8500 then create new file with .csv extention

```
sno name amnt
1  Larry  8500
3  Perl   8500
```

based on `amnt`
how to do this please let me know?
your suggestion will be appreciable.
i tried like

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new;
open(my$new,"<", 'file.csv') or die "oops!";
open(my$old,">" ,'file2.csv' ) or die "Oops!";
while (my@line =<$new>) {
    print $old $line[1]->[1],"\n";
}
close $new;
close $old;
```

Comment: You are still not using the Text::CSV module. At least you managed to create an object by now. Anyway, what is the problem? Is the code not working? Are there any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

It's a one-liner :-)

```
perl -ane '($.==1 || $F[2] == 8500) && print' file1.csv > file2.csv
sno name amnt
1  Larry  8500
3  Perl   8500
```

Sorry! I am only joking - I know my answer isn't very constructive for teaching Perl, except maybe [TIMTOWTDI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it).

The `$.==1` causes the header line to be printed because line number is 1.

The `-a` causes Perl to split the fields of each line into an array `@F` for us.

The `-n` says to put a while loop around the program (thanks @TLP)

The `$F[2]` refers to field 3.

Comment: the out put file stored in file

Comment: The `-n` switch puts a `while(<>)` loop around the program. The printing is only when comparing it with the `-p` switch which puts `while (<>) ... } continue { print }`

Comment: Thanks @TLP - too much sed-ing lately:-)